# EXTJS fireEvent

Tags: event-handling, extjs3

In the Ext.panel component, there is an event called expand(Ext.panel p).

Now I have 2 panels, A and B. The requirement is both of them should expand and collapse together. So when I expand A, i somehow need to fire the 'expand' event for B also. That should in turn fire the event handler for B.
So the syntax (please help me with this):

```
A.on('expand', userPanelExpand)//event handler for A that performs some logic
```

Now how can I add a fireEvent('expand') for B? Should it read:

```
A.on('expand', userPanelExpand);
function userPanelExpand(){
//some logic
this.fireEvent('expand', this.B);
}
```

Something not right here.I get Stackvoerflow error at the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A.on('expand', userPanelExpand, this);
B.on('expand', userPanelExpand, this);

// this will not go into recursion because if panel is already expanded then expand event will not be fired if we call panel.expand()
function userPanelExpand(panel) {
   if(panel === A) {
      B.expand();
   } else {
      A.expand();
   }
}
```